# Migration for changing on_delete option on references column

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I was playing with Phoenix and making has_many associations. I usually do `on_delete: :delete_all` as an option to the reference column. But if I change my mind and want to change it later for `nilify_all`, is there a way to this with inside a migration?

Migration for creating the table:

```
  def change do
    create table(:messages) do
      add :body, :text
      add :sender_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)

      timestamps()
    end
    create index(:messages, [:sender_id])

  end
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
def change do
  change_options table(:messages), :user_id, on_delete: :nilify_all
end
```

I've seen [modify](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#modify/3) and [alter](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#alter/2) but I didn't see anything about on_delete. Maybe it's not possible via migrations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `modify` for this, passing the new `on_delete` options in the new `type`, but I encountered [this bug](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/722#issuecomment-267778587) while trying this, the fix for which is to manually `DROP` the constraint first. You'll also need to specify both an `up` and a `down` version since `modify` is not reversible.

```
def up do
  execute "ALTER TABLE posts DROP CONSTRAINT posts_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:posts) do
    modify(:user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all))
  end
end

def down do
  execute "ALTER TABLE posts DROP CONSTRAINT posts_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:posts) do
    modify(:user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the doc about modifying did not show anything about references, I was thinking that it can't be done this way. And Thanks for the link about the bug I think you skip me an headache !

Comment: Thanks for this answer, much appreciated! Might be worth to mention that you now can use `drop constraint("table_name", "constraint_name")` instead of execute.

Answer (score 2):

[This Elixir Forum post](https://elixirforum.com/t/can-you-modify-a-columns-references-3-options-in-ecto/4443/10) notes that `modify()` can take a `:from` option; this lets you use `change` instead of `up`/`down`, and it will drop the previous constraint for you:

```
def change do
  alter table(:messages) do
    modify :sender_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nilify_all),
      from: references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.